# Paying taxes for a postdoc fellowship when there's no withholdings

Tags: united-states, postdocs

For 11 months last year, I was a postdoc employee and received a W2 for that. For the 12th month, I was a postdoc at the same institution, but on a fellowship. I received no form (e.g., no 1099-MISC or other) for that month apart from my paystub. What do I do for taxes? My paystub breaks down my earnings from the fellowship into “Stipend for Health Allowance” and “Stipend for Living Expenses”. The former is very high on the fellowship, but I never see a penny since it goes to health insurance at around 8x the cost of the deductions before the fellowship. Part of the latter "stipend" also goes toward health insurance. I would hope I only pay taxes on the latter stipend, which is the exact same amount I was making before the fellowship when I was a regular employee. How do I indicate this situation to the IRS? Can somebody please give me some insight here?

Comment: My suggestion would be to consult your universities human resources office.

Comment: I already did. They say they can't / won't comment on tax matters. I'm totally in the dark about this.

Comment: There are quite a few questions on [Personal Finance and Money SE](https://money.stackexchange.com/search?q=fellowship) about fellowships. You may want to read them.

Comment: In the US, fellowships are often considered taxable income. However, dealing with the taxes is on you. Plenty of materials around, including likely at your fellowship funding agency.

Comment: Find a CPA. It's their job to figure these sorts of things out.

Comment: What country? Even down to what state/province?  My only experience is in Canada. Here you very definitely have to pay income tax on things like post-docs. Scholarships also. The revenue folks will follow you across the country and empty your bank account without warning.